# Visual Studio 2012 + IIS 8.0 = how to deploy WCF service on localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have a `Wcf Service Application` project that is referenced by and used in different projects. Everything works fine when started Visual Studio 2012 - IIS Express is launched, hosted on localhost.

I tried to use `Publish` option in right-click menu of my `Wcf Service Application`. I created a new profile for publishing:

[image: Connection settings]
[image: Settings]

Hitting `Publish` works. I can access it through internet browser through `http://localhost`. However, when I launch my application normally, through the executable in bin/Debug - it doesn't work (app crashes). What should I do? Can I upload it and configure it easily with IIS Manager (tried it, but get some access errors)? I would need that in my virtual machine which doesn't have any VS installed.

What's troubling me is that in my `Wcf Service Application` project's `Web.config` file I have base addresses specified like this: `http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/MailingListService/` and in clients `App.config` I have endpoints with addresses like this: `http://localhost/MailingListService.svc`. Is it ok to have different ports and addresses (one is in root, the other in `WcfServiceLibrary`)? It works fine when run in Visual Studio.

`Web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NewsletterEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NewsletterDAL_EF.csdl|res://*/NewsletterDAL_EF.ssdl|res://*/NewsletterDAL_EF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Newsletter;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFHost.MessageService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFHost.IMessageService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/MessageService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFHost.MailingListService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFHost.IMailingListService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/MailingListService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFHost.RecipientService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFHost.IRecipientService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/RecipientService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFHost.SenderService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFHost.ISenderService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/SenderService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

`App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMessageService" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRecipientService" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMailingListService" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISenderService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2433/MessageService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMessageService"
                contract="MessageServiceReference.IMessageService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMessageService" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/RecipientService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRecipientService"
                contract="RecipientServiceReference.IRecipientService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRecipientService" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/MailingListService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMailingListService"
                contract="MailingListServiceReference.IMailingListService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IMailingListService" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/SenderService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISenderService" contract="SenderServiceReference.ISenderService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ISenderService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I forget the details so only a comment.  You need to have the client point to IIS and update endpoints.

Comment: I did that, but now I get a `FaultException` while trying to call a WCF service call.

Example of current `App.config`'s endpoint:

`<endpoint address="http://localhost/MessageService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMessageService" contract="MessageServiceReference.IMessageService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IMessageService" />`

Comment: I think you need to add a behavior for the mex

Comment: Look at my `Web.config`. There already is `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

dont bother anything. just do the following:
1) enter localhost in service url field. 
2) The name of the website you have added  inside the inetmgr in the site field.